# css: show a halved font-based icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I use a font-based iconset (in my case font-awesome 4.7 icons) which is used like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
```

What I would like to do is to overlay a triangle in the lower right corner so that it would look similar to the fa-eye-slash icon.

Is it possible to add a css class (like `<i class="fa fa-eye bottom-right-triangle"></i>`) which overlays a triangle and thus obscures half of the icon?

Comment: Don't think so, seeing something might get overridden, your best bet is to align two spans on top of each other and you should get your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this using `linear-gradient` and pseudo element as an ovrelay:

```css
.hide {
  position:relative;
}
.hide:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,#fff 50.5%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<i class="fas fa-eye fa-5x hide"></i>
```